# "Failed to construct the final file" on Fusion Inventory package deployment

Tags: inventory

I everyone !

I'm trying to learn how to use Fusion Inventory for deploying application on a Windows computer (for testing purposes).

When i start a task for deploying my application (notepad++) Fusion Inventory status is at Error and the deployment isn't working.

Fusion Inventory log:
`failed to prepare work dir`

Agent log:

```
[Mon Jul 11 14:16:43 2022][info] target server0: server http://X.X.X.X/glpi/plugins/fusioninventory/
[Mon Jul 11 14:16:43 2022][info] sending prolog request to server0
[Mon Jul 11 14:16:44 2022][info] running task Deploy
[Mon Jul 11 14:16:44 2022][info] Failed to construct the final file.: C:\Program Files (x86)\FusionInventory-Agent\var\http..__X.X.X.X_glpi_plugins_fusioninventory_\deploy/workdir/62cc149e32ef8/npp.8.4.2.Installer.x64.exe
[Mon Jul 11 14:16:48 2022][info] running task Inventory
[Mon Jul 11 14:16:48 2022][info] New inventory from DFormation-001.i2cx.formations-2022-07-08-15-32-08 for server0
[Mon Jul 11 14:17:42 2022][info] running task Collect
[Mon Jul 11 14:17:42 2022][info] No Collect job enabled or Collect support disabled server side.
```

I created a package on Fusion Inventory that refers to the notepad.exe installer placed on the GLPI server (Linux). The task is created and a job is made to target the computer. I gave a few commands on the package deployment to manage the installer when it is deployed:

```
 - Create a directory
 c:/deploiement
 - Move
 from * to c:\deploiement
 - Command
 c:\deploiement\npp.8.4.2.Installer.x64.exe
 - Command 
 del c:\deploiement\npp.8.4.2.Installer.x64.exe
 - Delete a directory
 c:\deploiement\
```

Job configuration

```
Method: Package deployment
Target: Package > Notepad
Actors: Computer > My computer's agent
```

GLPI Version: 10.0.0

Fusion Inventory Version: 10.0.0+1.1

Thanks for your time :)